# How can I enable wireless on my Clevo Zeus laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, laptop, clevo

I've gotten a laptop from around 2002, labeled "Clevo Zeus". It supposedly has wireless support: The chassis has a LED indicator for it. But  with the currently-installed OS (Windows XP), I can't find it in the device manager, and the taskbar says it's disabled. A TP-link utility installed for it also can't find it.

(Naturally, the person who performed the installation is long gone and the laptop hasn't been used in years.)

My question: How, if at all, can I enable WiFi on this laptop?

Comment: It is entirely possible that it is a mini pci card that someone removed. Open up the laptop and check if it is fitted. If it is not then you might find a card slot with antenna cables going to it but no card.

Comment: @Mokubai: 1. Wouldn't an external card preclude the existence of a built-in LED indicator? 2. How can I check whether the laptop is "fitted" with an internal WiFi adapter? I mean, I can certainly do the unscrewing part, but what exactly would I be looking for?

Comment: I'm not saying an "external" card. Internal cards can still have hardware switches and power indicators. You need to prove that the hardware is there before you can use it, device manager suggests that it is not.

Comment: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/carte-wifi-express-wireless-clevo-W550EU-S-BJACKJA-/192349891141 found via Google: https://www.google.com/search?&q=Clevo+Zeus+WiFi+card

Comment: @Mokubai: Thanks, I'll do that. Perhaps you want to  make your comments into a partial answer? Anyway, I'm hoping it's some sort of a power-saving feature which makes it look like the hardware isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

If the wifi does not show up in device manager then you have two options:

1. The wifi hardware has been removed and will need to be replaced.
2. The wifi hardware has failed and will need to be replaced, reseated or otherwise examined to find out what is wrong.

At the absolute minimum you will need to verify that the hardware exists and is present in your laptop. Given its vintage it is entirely possible that it was scavenged for parts to get another machine working.

You are looking for a small card with one or, more likely, two u.fl antenna connectors like this:

[image]

[Found on eBay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/carte-wifi-express-wireless-clevo-W550EU-S-BJACKJA-/192349891141) from a [cursory Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Clevo%20Zeus%20WiFi%20card&tbm=isch).

Alternatively to get Wifi working you could just buy a cheap USB wifi dongle. They are cheap, easy to find, and potentially faster than whatever was installed on a 20 year old laptop.

Comment: Does the bottom connector have a name, by the way? Or is it... PCI?

Comment: In newer computers it is m.2 which can pass PCIe, SATA and USB signals. The specific card above is probably more likely mini PCIe: https://www.ebuyer.com/392440-intel-centrino-wireless-n-2230-network-adapter-pci-express-half-mini-2230bn-hmwwb-2230bnhmw and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_Mini_Card. The best way to know for certain is to read your laptop manual for what expansion cards it might be able to fit.